# What's the reason ERC-20 standard allows 0 value transfer?

Tags: erc-20

ERC-20 says `transfer` and `transferFrom` should allow 0-value transfer and fire `Transfer` event. What's the main benefit of allowing 0-value transfer? Is there any use case?

Comment: No particular reason. I've opened a discussion about this topic on Twitter: [I have always found it annoying that ERC-20 allows zero-value transfers](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1644318310165626880)

Answer (score 3):

Usually you will not see a hardcoded transfer(0).

But there are use cases like transfer(b-c).  If 0 value transfers were not allowed and generated an exception, developers would have to explicitly handle the case when c equals b.  Allowing 0 value transfers is safe from bugs, but disallowing them can create more work for developers, and standards should be easy to use correctly.

Comment: Hard to think someone doing that without knowing in detail what he is transferring. At least knowing c >= b...

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to prevent it. If you want to transfer 0 tokens it is meaningless operation but it doesn't produce any harm. You will be paying the transaction fee.

For example it is allowed to transfer 0 ethers. It doesn't make much sense but you still have to pay the transaction fee. They are used to override stuck transactions with lowers fees.

Answer (score 0):

There is great harm to allowing 0 balance transfers.  Scammers can create "fake" transaction history in users' wallets and rip users off who do not check the whole of the recipient address when sending currency.  Wallets are not that great yet at providing address books to prevent this.  You might say that users should be responsible and beware, but most humans are not blockchain developers and this is still a horrible usability issue that only a programmer could love.